# Static or non-static methods used as the Func parameter in a Task<TResult> constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I am writing a set of classes all derived from a base class. I want to be able to run multiple Task threads. Can the Func() used in the constructor of the Task be an instance method or does it have to be a class static method? If it is an instance method, can multiple Tasks be started using the same non-static method?

Comment: Yes and yes. But be careful that the method you call is thread save.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be conflating *static* and *non static* methods with *thread safety*, for lack of a better term... *thread safety* is probably as imprecise as a term can be, but it'll work in the present context. This is the completely wrong thing to ask, so unlearn whatever you think you know about the supposedly inbred safety of *static* members.

The rule is that what you are asking is *safe(+)* as long as its safe to call that same method concurrently. When is this safe? Well, in broad terms, when the method only writes or reads local variables, only reads immutable shared data or there is some sort of synchronization implemented that allows it to read and/or write concurrently to shared data.

(+) Understand *safe* as the condition where your code will do what you expect it to do.

Comment: So if I am using something like a ConcurrentQueue to get the data my Tasks will be working on, then I can use either a static method OR an instance method?

Comment: @JNickVA1 Again, static or non static is a non factor here. Also using `ConcurrentQueue` doesn't make anything inherently safe, it depends how you are using it. But yes, lacking any other information, if you are using it correctly, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: One thing is threadsafe with ConcurrentQueue: Adding and retreiving of items. All they propably do is using lock statements in the proper methods (on the same Mutex object). But processing beyond that is a vulnerable to race conditons as anything else.

Comment: I chose the ConcurrentQueue because all I need is to retrieve items to perform actions on that will have no consequence on any other data. It (the ConcurrentQueue) appears to be exactly what I want in that respect. InBetween is very correct when saying that I'm a bit confused about static methods and instance methods being used as the Func when creating a Task<TResult>.